# How to override __iter__() for custom class?

Tags: python

What I'm trying to do is reuse generator

```
class Rect(object):
   ...
   def __iter__(self):
       for y in xrange(self.tl.y, self.br.y + 1):
           for x in xrange(self.tl.x, self.br.x + 1):
               yield Point(x, y)
```

in child class. I've tried write something like

```
class Block(Rect):
    ...
    def __iter__(self):
        for p in super(Block, self):
            yield p + self.offset
```

but obviously that didn't work.

My question is can that be done without copying code from parent class and what is most pythonic approach to re-usability of inherited code.

Comment: Perhaps it's a better idea to move `Rect.__iter__`'s implementation to a function (`_iter_as_rect`?) you can explicitly reuse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
class Block(Rect):
    def __iter__(self):
        for p in super(Block, self).__iter__():
            yield p + self.offset
```